# Deciding Initial Weights for Gradient Descent Algorithm

Tags: gradient-descent

Having done an interesting Coursera module on Linear Regression, and being provided with the starting values for Gradient Descent, I am wondering about some things that were not touched upon, and, for which I could not find the answer to:

1. What is the way to estimate the initital starting values for the weights? I do not seem to find anything here.

I think it does not matter if you have infinite computing power and time.

But, may be I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a [convex function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) it does not matter where to start. The objective function for linear regression using squared loss or least absolute difference loss are convex functions.

For non-convex functions, such as neural network, where to start matters a lot. Because even with infinite computing power and time, the gradient decent approach can still stuck with [local minima or saddle point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima). There are many work to discuss how to initialize neural network weights.

Comment: OK, but just a thought or a very stupid question: If I have a model and choose N features, how do I know if it will be a convex or non-convex function? If it is convex then no issue where to start weights from you state. But if not, then this is important. Also, the local mimina, saddle point I get, but still how do I know if we are using convex, concave or not?